# Android In-App Billing - Repurchase after reinstallation of app

Tags: android, in-app-billing

My application uses the Android Market In-App Billing Support and it works well for the first purchase done by user. However, when an user removes and installs the app again, when he/she purchases the same item, the Market keeps showing the following statement: "Your order is processing, your item will be available in a few minutes". And the Response Code is "RESULT_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE". What can I do to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

After studying the Android Developer - In-app Billing http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_overview.html, there is an operation called RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS, call it at the first launch of application solves the problem.